# can I change Svelte delimiter?

Tags: javascript, smarty, svelte, delimiter

I am working on a big project that use Smarty template engine with AngularJs and we need to move out from AngularJs to Svelte. we face a bad problem that the delimiter of smarty is the same as Svelte and I had been searched for any solution to change delimiter of Svelte and I have been got nothing.
So, please I need to know if this possible to change Svelte delimiter or not?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: I don't see why would you ever use php vars inside your svelte component in the first place?

Comment: I don't use php vars,  only using a lot of config vars {#LNG_VAR#} for localization. @SherifSalah

Comment: @abdekrazekmostafa in this case you need ajax request to return a JSON object from a local file or the database whatever, but there is no scenario whatsoever where you use template engine with a frontend framework or use php vars within a js file.

Answer (score 0):

Changing the delimiter is **NOT** possible.

The `{` and `}` are hardcoded into the Svelte compiler.